# Format error when trying to parse datetime string using strptime

Tags: python, strptime, date-parsing

Trying to parse a datetime string to unix:

```
from calendar import timegm
from datetime import datetime

print(timegm(datetime.strptime(('2021-07-21 00:00:07.223977216+00:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')))
```

Results in

```
ValueError: time data '2021-07-21 00:00:07.223977216+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+00:00'
```

Tried a lot, cant get anywhere so far ...

Answer (score 1):

Your date is in ISO format, so you can use `datetime.fromisoformat`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromisoformat("2021-07-21 00:00:07+00:00")
datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 21, 0, 0, 7, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Comment: somehow the timezone seems to get messed up. when I enter

print(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2021-07-21 00:00:07+00:00").utctimetuple()))

in an epochcounter it returns  GMT: Tuesday, July 20, 2021 10:00:07 PM

Answer (score 0):

So if you look at the format of the date time you are providing, it does not have the fractional seconds the formatter is looking for:

```py
# '2021-07-21 00:00:07+00:00' <- this date time
# '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'      <- in this format, is parsing like below
# 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.ff' (note the ff part is missing, then there's a +00:00 part leftover so the format is breaking)
```

If you don't need the microseconds, remove the '.%f' part from your format string. Otherwise, if you're parsing a series of values where some have the fractional part, you're going to need to give both options:

```py
try:
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(your_string_here, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
except ValueError:
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(your_string_here, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: sadly I need the exact timestamp :/

Comment: I understand, but the format string you've put on the end (%f) is if you have a decimal amount of seconds, when in fact the suffix you have on your timestamp (+00:00) is TZ offset, so EITHER you have put the +00:00 bit there for milliseconds and not realised the format is overloaded, OR you do mean for it to mean timezone and you actually need `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z` as your format string.

Comment: Ah yes, then you need both the .%f and the %z parts. Your format is officially `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z`, but the problem you're now encountering is that [python date time only supports up to 6 decimal places for the %f operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66266454/strptime-f-directive-cant-handle-more-than-6-decimal-places).